# Read from ngxs store

Tags: angular, store, ngxs

I want to read data from store if given date(payload) is available in the state.

else i should get it from service and put it in a store.

```
    @Action(GetCreditWidget)
    getForms({ getState, setState,patchState }: StateContext<CreditStateModel>, { creditdate }: GetCreditWidget) {
        
        const state = getState();

    let titleAvailable = false;
   
    const newState =  state.credits.map(title => {
      if (title.date === creditdate) {
        titleAvailable = true;
       setState({
          ...state,
          selectedcredit: title,
        });
        return title;

      }
    });
  if (!titleAvailable) {
    return this.creditwidgetService.getnewstate(creditdate).pipe(tap((result1) => {
        const state = getState();
            patchState({
            ...state,
            credits: result1 as any,
        });
    }));
    }
    }
```

Comment: What's the question? Are you wanting to know if you're following best practices, or does your code not work. Help us help you.

Comment: How to make the code execution synchronous

Comment: I think you're out of luck there, the point of using NGXS over something like NGRX is that action execution is asynchronous. Why do you need the action handler to be synchronous? The actions are handled in an observable.